# Capture just version from tox commands

Tags: python, bash, shell, sed, tox

I have following in my tox.ini :

```
[tox]
skipsdist = true
envlist = py27, py36, lint

[testenv]
whitelist_externals=flake8
commands =
    version: python setup.py --version
```

When I run

> tox -e version

I get the following output :

```
tox -e version 2>version
version runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='3264081464'
version runtests: commands[0] | python setup.py --version
0.2.0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
  version: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

I need to capture just the version (**0.2.0**) from ***tox -e version*** output, what the most elegant/pythonic way of doing it ? Also is there anyway I can have tox just output the output to the command and not the rest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the version into a file. In `tox.ini`:

```
[testenv]
whitelist_externals = /bin/sh
commands =
    version: /bin/sh -c "python setup.py --version >version"
```

In shell:

```
tox -e version
cat version
rm version
```

Answer (score 0):

Including `-qq` in the `tox` command should reduce the output to just `0.2.0`.

Comment: That still prints :
 ➜  oktapod git:(master) ✗ tox -qq -e version

```0.2.0
  version: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)```